# how can configure for the scenario " thread, test will execute for 10 mins but need 60 seconds break after 1 mins running." in jmeter?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I've to run a test like- 1 thread, test will execute for 10 mins but need 60 seconds break after 1 mins running.

my target is- how many thread or request is processed for a scenario that configured test will run for 10 mins but 60 secs hold/stop in every 1 mins of thread running.

Please help how to configure above mentioned scenario..

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can create a delay/pause in your test using JMeter Timers, for your case the easiest is going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin), example configuration:

[image]

---

However you can achieve the same without having to install any plugins:

1. Put your Sampler(s) under the [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) and configure it to run for 1 minute

   [image]
2. Add Flow Control Action sampler after the Runtime Controller and configure it to pause for 1 minute

   [image]